# In Android Project, Single File has R errors

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, resources

I have a project working perfectly on Windows in Eclipse. As most of my work is now on a Mac at my job, I'm switching over to Eclipse for Mac.

I have fixed all of the build path errors across the project, and all that remains are the "this_xml_name cannot be resolved or is not a field", in theory resulting in an error when building my R file.

However, this is the first I have encountered this problem appearing only in a single file, and it is not just id's or layouts. It happens in R.layout, R.id, R.menu, and R.drawable. All other references throughout my project are perfectly fine, only errors are found at each of the R. references in the linked file.

MapActivity.java

```
package com.example.android;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        FragmentActivity activity = this;

        private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
        protected GoogleMap mMap;
        String locAddr;
        String locName;
        Double locLongitude;
        Double locLatitude;
        final Handler handler = new Handler();


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


                if (servicesOK()) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

                        if (initMap()) {
                                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                                if (extras != null) {
                                        locAddr = extras.getString("address");
                                        locName = extras.getString("name");
                                        locLongitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
                                        locLatitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");

                                        activity.setTitle(locName);

                                        Timer timer = new Timer();
                                        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {

                                                         handler.post(new Runnable()
                                                    {
                                                        public void run()
                                                        {
                                                                LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(locLatitude, locLongitude);

                                                                                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 14.0f));

                                                                                Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                                                                        .position(coordinates)
                                                                                        .title(locName)
                                                                                        .snippet(locAddr)
                                                                                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker)));

                                                                                marker.showInfoWindow();
                                                                                /*mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                                                                                        @Override
                                                                                        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                                                                                                Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                                                                                                intent.putExtra("userkey", "MattCoker");
                                                                                                intent.putExtra("geolat", "29.7530");
                                                                                                intent.putExtra("geolong", "geozip");
                                                                                                intent.putExtra("clientid", "0");
                                                                                                intent.putExtra("siteid", "0");
                                                                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                                                        }
                                                                                });*/
                                                        }
                                                    });

                                                }
                                        }, 3000);


                                } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Something went wrong displaying this location!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                        }
                }
                else {
                        setContentView(R.layout.no_available_maps);
                }

                //Show the Up button in the action bar.
                setupActionBar();


        }

        /**
         * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
         */
        private void setupActionBar() {

                activity.getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        }

        public boolean servicesOK() {
                int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);

                if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                        return true;
                }
                else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
                        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable, activity, GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST);
                        dialog.show();
                }
                else {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Can't connect to Google Play Services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return false;
        }

        private boolean initMap() {
                if (mMap == null) {
                        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = null;
                        mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                        mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
                }
                return (mMap != null);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

            // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
            /*SearchManager searchManager =
                   (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView searchView =
                    (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                    searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));*/

            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

                int selectedMenuItem = item.getItemId();

                if (selectedMenuItem == R.id.action_settings) {
                        Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(activity, SettingsActivity.class);
                        startActivity(settingsIntent);
                        return true;
                } else if (selectedMenuItem == R.id.send_feedback) {
                        Intent sendFeedback = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendFeedback.setType("message/rfc822");
                        sendFeedback.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"usersupport@example.com"});
                        sendFeedback.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback on example...");

                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendFeedback, "Send Email"));

                        //TODO: Create Feedback Activity to send email

                        return true;
                }
                return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: delete R.java file and rebuild your project again.

Comment: replace import android.R with import com.example.android.R;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have errors in your resource files `R.java` will not be generated. Fix those errors and clean and build.

Looking at the code you  have

```
import android.R;
```

Replace it with

```
import com.example.android.R;
```